# How can track execution in C++ without using a debugger?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple C++ program;

```
int someFunction()
{
    cout << "Testing here" << endl;
    cout << "reached here in function " << __LINE__ << " in " << __FUNCTION__ << endl; // debug purposes

    // do some more stuffs here

    cout << "reached here in function " << __LINE__ << " in " << __FUNCTION__ << endl; // debug purpsoes
}
```

Is there a way of switching on/off the lines of codes marked as "debug purposes"? The ideas is in case of problems I can just write a one liner to switch on those kind of debug purpose codes and when solved switch them off.

I know debuggers are for this very purpose, but want something simple for simple programs.

Comment: Ever heard of [conditional defines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it in a conditional define:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    // Debugcode here
#endif
```

When you are done debugging, just define `NDEBUG` during compilation. You might also want to have a look at [`assert`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) It is controlled by the same macro `NDEBUG` and easily lets you check conditions in you program. You can also have it produce meaningful error messages:

```
assert(allWentWell && "Blah went wrong!");
```

The error-message of assert will also include information to where the error occurred.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of the other replies, you could declare a global flag:

```
 #ifndef NDEBUG
 bool want_debug;
 #endif /*NDEBUG*/
```

then define a macro

```
 #ifndef NDEBUG
 #define DEBUG_OUT(Expr) do {if (want_debug)   \
    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " " \
         << Expr << endl;} while(0)
 #else
 #define DEBUG_Out(Expr) do{}while(0)
 #endif
```

and you'll add a lot of statements like

```
 DEBUG_OUT("here x="<< x);
```

The `want_debug` flag could be set at runtime (e.g. inside a debugger, or with some `-d` program argument handled by your `main`). If you compile with `-DNDEBUG` you won't get any code for `DEBUG_OUT` statements.

I'm using the `NDEBUG` preprocessor symbol related to the old [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html).

Of course, be careful to avoid meaningful side-effects in `DEBUG_OUT`, e.g. 
 `DEBUG_OUT("here y=" << y++); /*WRONG side effect*/` is certainly a mistake.

If using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (e.g. `g++` version 4.9), you could also customize it using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) by adding magically (in your customizing extension coded in MELT) some pass which would automatically add logging messages (e.g. at end of every routine). But that might means weeks of work (so is worthwhile for big existing software projects).

Answer (score 3):

The classical way to solve this is to define some logging macros; a simple example may be:

```
#ifdef_NDEBUG
#    define LOG(X) 
#else
#    define LOG(X) do { std::clog<<__FILE__<<":"<<__LINE__<<" "<<(X)<<std::endl;} while(0)
#endif
```

Usage:

```
LOG("Before frobbing the widget (i="<<i<<")");
```

Of course this can be taken to any level of complexity (there are quite a few libraries that approach the problem of logging).

Comment: Looks a lot like my answer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I noticed, and I upvoted yours since it's more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Is you want to "switch on/off" some part of code, you can use macros and preprocessor directives #ifdef and #endif:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
//run this code
#endif
```

Above code will only run, if _DEBUG macro is defined:

```
#define _DEBUG
```

Comment: `_DEBUG` is an implementation reserved identifier and must not be used in user-code.